# Why does this site fit perfectly in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The site which can be viewed [here](http://directdatanou.comli.com/) contains all `div` elements inside a `wrapper div` with the following propreties:

```
#content_wrapper{   
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 1280px;
}
```

The inner content (for example DESPRE NOI section) has a static `width` of `960px` (`#despre_noi` has class `.latime_960`)

```
.latime_960 {
width: 960px;
}
```

Even though the main wrapper has `min-width:1280px` and the inner content has a static, `960px width`, **the site fits perfectly on mobile**. I tested it on a Samsung S3 and on a very old LG, in both portrait and landscape modes.

It fits perfectly. Why? Is it just by accident or I can keep this design and it will fit fine on all mobile devices?

Comment: It doesn't look good in mobile view for me, not responsive at all. Using safari on OS X.

Comment: I don't think your site is responsive, for responsive design you need @media query [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: @nextstep Thank you, I did not test it with that browser

Comment: @ichadhr Yes, that's why it seemed strange to work without media queries - but now I realise I only used Chrome to test it on both phones -  for example I understand it won't work on Safari

Comment: @HelloLili maybe chrome mobile have features optimized for mobile view? don't know.. I don't use chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The website does not use the [Viewport Meta Tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) and therefor the mobile browser is scaling the content to fit the screen.

Edit: I recommend using the Viewport Meta Tag and placing your mobile layout styles at the top of your CSS declarations followed by media queries for the CSS needed for your large screens/devices. Browser scaling may look fine at first but it is very likely you will experience font legibility or touch target interface issues when you rely on the browser scaling.

Answer (score 1):

Your website doesn't load for some reason. Are you using 000webhost?
& to what you asked in the Q... its most likely because of position: relative;

edit: " .... programmed to view thew website as a whole if it is not programmed by the developed to be mobile friendly. If you add a media query to make it so that a size of a div changes based on a height and width of the screen, then you will see the change ..."

Comment: Yes, I am using 000webhost

Comment: I saw the website, it looks great. I tried tweaking with the mobile web view on chrome, and it seems to be fine. 
What actually happens is that mostly all smart phones like the iPhones or the newly released androids are programmed to view thew website as a whole if it is not programmed by the developed to be mobile friendly. If you add a media query to make it so that a size of a div changes based on a height and width of the screen, then you will see the change. Thats basically it. Hope you understood what I said lol.